# Can the NASA Ingenuity Copter record video with its camera?

Tags: mars, photography, helicopter, ingenuity

I'm wondering whether the Ingenuity Helicopter on Mars as part of the Perseverance rover can record moving video in addition to still images, and if the video can then be sent back to Earth.

Comment: I think there are several paths to consider and I'm not sure which ones you are asking about; 1) direct to Earth, 2) to Perseverance then Earth, and 3) to Perseverance, then a Mars-orbiting satellite, then Earth.

Comment: Primarily interested in whether the camera on the helicopter can record video (not just stills), rather than the route it takes back to Earth. I think it would be the first true video footage from another planet?

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your question to better match what you've written in comments. Does it look okay?

Comment: All different, but related: [Could “live” video be transmitted from Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32295/12102) and [Will the Mars 2020 rover be able to record high-framerate video of its helicopter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40975/12102) and [Why are there no video transmissions from the Moon and Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/993/12102) and [Transmission of video and audio signals](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39157/12102)

Answer (score 6):

NASA just confirmed in the press conference that the copter can transmit colour video, around 18:44 GMT in this video link (approx 49 minutes from the start)

Comment: Random comment. The guy in the video is wearing two watches.

Comment: Rover time and local time?

Comment: That actually is possibly correct. JPL has their staff work on Mars time, which has a day 40 minutes longer than Earth's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol_(day_on_Mars). I imagine it might be tough to find a watch that supports non-24hr days, so maybe they just reset it every work day. Another explanation would be not needing to use the smart watch display for checking the time.